# Jenkinsfile: How do I print a boolean?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to do the following as debugging output in a Jenkinsfile:

```
echo fileExists("path/to/some/file")
```

This does, however, not work. `fileExists` returns a boolean, which can apparently not be implicitly cast to a string, and the `echo` command wants a string.

So what's the correct way to print a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${fileExists("path/to/some/file")}"
```

or more generally

```
echo "${boolean_expression}"
```

works. Is this how you're supposed to do it?